# Is clang right to give a redefinition error of this partial specialization using std::void_t?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Given this example...

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct FooBlarg;
template <typename T, typename U, typename = void> struct Blip;
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Blip<T, U, std::void_t<decltype(FooBlarg<T, U>::value)>>
{
};
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Blip<T, U, std::void_t<typename T::zz, typename T::yy>>
{
};
```

clang emits this error...

```
<source>:14:8: error: redefinition of 'Blip<T, U, std::void_t<typename T::zz, typename T::yy> >'
struct Blip<T, U, std::void_t<typename T::zz, typename T::yy>>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:10:8: note: previous definition is here
struct Blip<T, U, std::void_t<decltype(FooBlarg<T, U>::value)>>
```

However, gcc does not give this error.  I tried with both libc++ and libstdc++, so I then got rid of the standard library entirely with this example.

```
template <typename...> using myvoid1 = void;

template <typename...> struct myvoid2_ { using type = void; };
template <typename ... Ts> using myvoid2 = typename myvoid2_<Ts...>::type;

template <typename T, typename U> struct FooBlarg;
template <typename T, typename U, typename = void> struct Blip;
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Blip<T, U, VOIDT<decltype(FooBlarg<T, U>::value)>>
{
};
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Blip<T, U, VOIDT<typename T::zz, typename T::yy>>
{
};
```

If I `#define VOIDT myvoid1`, which is the most likely implementation of std::void_t, then I get the exact same compiler error.  However, if I `#define VOIDT myvoid2`, which is the alternate implementation that has been used to get around a problem that has supposedly been fixed, then it works as I expect.

Obviously, clang does not have the original issue referred to in CWG 1558, because other use cases are not problematic.

So, is clang wrong here, or are both gcc and my expectations wrong for these specializations?

I looked for a bug report and the closes I found was this one: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33655

Thanks!

Comment: @Barry I do not think the answers in the other question answer this.  I believe I understand what is happening - my question is whether this is intended or is it a bug?  clang and gcc treat the exact same code differently.  I want to know which is correct - and why.  However, now that is has been closed, I don't know if anyone will see this comment...

Comment: Furthermore, note that this has nothing to do with the standard library, because it is neither included nor used here.  It has to do with the difference between the alias template and the class template, and whether clang is wrong for giving the error or gcc is wrong for not giving the error.

Comment: It's a core language issue. The correct behavior is an open question.